# Popup a New aspx Page to View Documents

Tags: javascript, webforms

I have a linkbutton in a gridview which - onClick should redirect to a blank.aspx form and carrying with it an ID. I have done this but I am getting an error that this is not well-formed:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbView" runat="server" Text="View"
       OnClientClick="window.open('DocumentViewer.aspx?ID=<%# Bind("ID") %>')">
</asp:LinkButton>
```

I wonder what is wrong with this, could you please let me know. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbView" runat="server" Text="View"
       OnClientClick="window.open('DocumentViewer.aspx?ID=<%# Eval("ID") %>')">
</asp:LinkButton>
```

if the above din work,then try this one..

```
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbView" runat="server"  Text="View"   
           PostBackUrl="window.open('DocumentViewer.aspx?ID=<%# Eval("ID") %>')">
    </asp:LinkButton>
```

or

```
     <asp:LinkButton ID="lbView" runat="server" Text="View"  
           PostBackUrl="window.open(&#34;DocumentViewer.aspx?ID='<%# Eval("ID")%>'&#34;)">
     </asp:LinkButton>
```

or

give CommandName = "eject" for  linkbutton.. then use GridView RowCommand event.

```
if(e.CommandName =="eject") 
{ 
int index = convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
string id = GridView1.DataKeys[idx].Value.ToString();
Response.redirect("DocumentViewer.aspx?‌​id='"+id+"'");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it actually still returning the same error as above even when I changed it to use Eval instead of Bind.

Comment: If you tried all the three and it dint work,then check in the console for the exact error..

Comment: The error always is that this server tag is not well-formed. It works if I remove the ?ID=<%# Eval("ID") %>' part of it, but I need that.

Comment: No, again it didn't: OnClientClick="window.open('DocumentViewer.aspx?ID='+'<%# Eval("ID", "DocumentViewer.aspx?id={0}") %>'

Comment: give CommandName = "eject" in linkbutton..
then use GridView RowCommand event.

if(e.CommandName =="eject") 
{
 int index = convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
 string id = GridView1.DataKeys[idx].Value.ToString();Response.redirect("DocumentViewer.aspx?id='"+id+"'")
}

Comment: Thank you. this is actually having some issues with me too, so many bugs that it didn't work either. Its ok, I will find out what is happening.